# Why is sphinx-autoapi displaying an empty API reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I can not get this to work;

I have the following structure

```
testdoc/
   __init__.py
   docs/ #sphinx directory
   lib/
       __init__.py
       a.py
```

a.py contains a single class with docstrings.

I initialized a fresh sphinx doc in testdoc/docs, and changed my config.py to:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
[...]
extensions = ['autoapi.extension','sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram']
autoapi_modules = {'testdoc.lib.a': {}}

# Document Python Code
autoapi_type = 'python'
autoapi_dirs = ['../lib']
[...]
```

I am using the html output.
AutoAPI reads the module testdoc.lib.a, and it generates a lot of files in docs/_build/autoapi:

```
index.html
testdoc/
        lib/
            index.html
            a/
              index.html
```

So the documentation is indeed generated and looks okay.

On the main page of the doc, there is a link to the API reference. However, this API reference does not link to the module; it is empty. Am I doing something wrong? I expected the module showing up in the API reference.

I attach the log file. I noticed that it refers to a file autoapi\testdoc\lib\a\index.rst that does not show up in my directory structure.

```
Running Sphinx v4.2.0
loading pickled environment... done
[AutoAPI] Reading files... [100%] testdoc\lib\__init__.py
[AutoAPI] Mapping Data... [100%] testdoc\lib\__init__.py
[AutoAPI] Rendering Data... [ 50%] testdoc.lib.a
[AutoAPI] Rendering Data... [100%] testdoc.lib

[autosummary] generating autosummary for: autoapi\index.rst, autoapi\testdoc\lib\a\index.rst, autoapi\testdoc\lib\index.rst, index.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 3 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 3 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] autoapi/testdoc/lib/index
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... testdoc\docs\autoapi\index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
testdoc\docs\autoapi\testdoc\lib\index.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
generating indices... genindex py-modindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 2 warnings.

The HTML pages are in _build\html.
```

Comment: What's in `docs`? The structure of your project should follow best practices: `projectrepo/docs/` and `projectrepo/src/projectname/`.

Comment: docs/ is the root of sphinx... it contains the conf.py, the Makefile, etc., and the build directories. I have also tried the same with separate source and build dirs, it did not make a difference.

Comment: `docs` contains no `.rst` files? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: It contains an index.rst, the conf.py, the Makefile. The index page of the documentation are generated fine, and I also can add content to it (like referencing other rst files). There is even the link to "API reference" in the index, the only thing missing is the actual content of said API reference.

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow the best practices, moving your docs outside of your Python package, as I described above. Then readjust your paths and update your question with the complete `conf.py`.